# Opening Google Map with Markers in Chrome Plugin

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an application and this chrome extension is part of that web application. Whenever user launches this extension it should display a map with predefined markers. Here is my sample code which I wrote test.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
          center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
          zoom:5,
          mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div id="loading">
        <div>
          <img src="img/sunny.png" />
          <p>Getting Data From Server</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="weather"></div>
        <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Main.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('weather.html', {
    id: 'weather',
    innerBounds: {
      height: 450,
      width: 300,
    },
    resizable: true
  });
});
```

It opens a popup window but doesn't load map. While this html file is working perfectly when I open it directly in a browser.

Comment: Have you got any error in the console? Or could you attach the manifest file?

Comment: By the way, you should add `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration at the beginning of the popup.html file.